# Mongo "not authorized for query" on user defined table while authenticated as dbOwner

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs, compose-db

I'm using is mongojs 2.3.0 to connect to a MongoDB cluster running 3.0. The user credentials I'm using to connect are for a user that has dbOwner privileges (so they should have read/write permissions for all collections).

The driver successfully makes a lot of queries, but there are a surprising number of queries that fail with the error in the title of my question ("not authorized for query"). I can also authenticate and query collections with the credentials from a mongo shell session.

Has anyone else ever encountered this issue before? Thanks!